# Heading doesn't stay above the cards

Tags: html, css, z-index

I was creating a site that manages notes. There is a header tag with a heading of "Notes", a tilted divider and bunch of notes as cards. I want the divider (a tilt made using svg) to stay below the cards and the header to ascent stay above the cards when scrolled. I made a code but header still stays below the cards.

Notes:

- I'm using z-index property to sort the layout
- I put the divider and the heading in the same container (is it a problem?)

Edit:

- I will add some icons in the header.
- Structural changes to HTML are also accepted
- I've added what layout I wanted below:
- Before scrolling it should look like this: [image]
- After scrolling a little bit, this is what I wanted: [image]

  ```css
  :root {
    --theme: #198754;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body,
  html {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Roboto, sans-serif;
  }

  main {
    height: 100%;
  }

  header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .heading {
    padding: 30px;
    z-index: 10; 
  }

  .custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194 svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
    height: 100px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194 .shape-fill {
    fill: #ffffff;
  }


  h2, h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }

  .notes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: var(--theme);
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .note {
    flex: 0 1 24%;
    box-shadow: #333333 0px 0px 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 1rem .25em;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .notes {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .note {
      flex: 0 1 100%;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .notes {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .note {
      flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 1em);
      max-width: calc(50% -  1em);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .card {
      flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 1em);
      max-width: calc(25% - 1em);
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <header>
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Notes</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="shape-divider">
      <div class="custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194">
        <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z" class="shape-fill"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="notes">
    <div class="note">
        <h2>Note 1</h2>
    </div> 
    <div class="note">
        <h2>Note 2</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="note">
        <h2>Note 3</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="note">
        <h2>Note 4</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="note">
        <h2>Note 5</h2>
     </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Add `z-index: 10;` to `header`

Comment: This is not the result the asker wants.

Comment: @navnath That doesn't work well

Answer (score 1):

You code cannot work properly because if you add `z-index` to your `header`, then whole the header with `background clip` will be above of the cards.
So I added a fixed `heading-main` to solve it.

```css
:root {
  --theme: #198754;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Roboto, sans-serif;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.heading {
  padding: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.heading-main {
  padding: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194 svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194 .shape-fill {
  fill: #ffffff;
}


h2, h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.notes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: var(--theme);
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.note {
  flex: 0 1 24%;
  box-shadow: #333333 0px 0px 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 1rem .25em;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 150px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .notes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .note {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .notes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .note {
    flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 1em);
    max-width: calc(50% -  1em);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .card {
    flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 1em);
    max-width: calc(25% - 1em);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="heading-main">
  <h1>Notes</h1>
</div>
<header>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Notes</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="shape-divider">
    <div class="custom-shape-divider-top-1633855194">
      <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M1200 120L0 16.48 0 0 1200 0 1200 120z" class="shape-fill"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="notes">
  <div class="note">
      <h2>Note 1</h2>
  </div> 
  <div class="note">
      <h2>Note 2</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="note">
      <h2>Note 3</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="note">
      <h2>Note 4</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="note">
      <h2>Note 5</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is close to what I want. But is there some more 'neat' way? Because, I will add more thinks like a settings icon, user icon, etc. in the header that stays above the cards when scrolled

Comment: You can add more icons and etc in your `header`, and `header-main` that have same style.

Comment: And, make opacity of those in `header` to 0.

Comment: Then it would work properly.

Comment: But wouldn't that be code duplication?

Comment: If you don't want code duplication, then you can set the `header` height by `heading-main` height instead of writing same code.